# How to programmatically scroll to the bottom of a Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll to the bottom of a recycler view on click of a button, how do I do this?

Answer (score 33):

You have to make use of `LayoutManager` for that. Follow the below steps.

**1).** First of all, declare `LayoutManager` in your `Activity/Fragment`. For example, I have taken `LinearLayoutManager`

```
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
```

**2).** Initialise the `LinearLayoutManager` and set that to your `RecyclerView`

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

**3).** On your `Button onClick`, do this to scroll to the bottom of your `RecyclerView`.

```
mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourList.size() - 1); // yourList is the ArrayList that you are passing to your RecyclerView Adapter.
```

Hope this will help..!!

Comment: 3) It should be mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourList.size() - 1);

Comment: If recycle view element is big (image for example) this show only start if item. So this not real scroll to bottom (I can still scroll more by hand after this)

Comment: @Alex Not working! Image in the list item is the cause?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown No. Problem is that scrollToPosition() scroll to top of last element. And need scroll to bottom of last element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [scrollToPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)) with the index of the last position.

Comment: Based on the doc, " RecyclerView does not implement scrolling logic, rather forwards the call to scrollToPosition(int)". It does not implement the logic, simply call this function will does nothing.

Comment: My apologies, on second look, it works.

Comment: Same as previous answer - If recycle view element is big (image for example) this show only start if item. So this not real scroll to bottom (I can still scroll more by hand after this)

Comment: This is not working. Image in the list item is the cause?